# Running VisIt from IPython

Tags: python, ipython

I'm trying to learn how to run [VisIt](https://wci.llnl.gov/codes/visit/) from the command line, and I've been able to make plots using `visit -cli` and giving Python commands, i.e. `OpenDatabase("somefile.vtk")`, etc.

Is there anyway to do the same thing except from the `ipython` interpreter?

I've tried

```
import visit
visit.OpenDatabase("somefile.vtk")
```

this gives me the error `'module' object has no attribute 'OpenDatabase'`

If, on the other hand, I run

```
import visit
visit.Launch()
visit.OpenDatabase("somefile.vtk")
...
```

The VisIt GUI is opened and everything after `visit.Launch()` is ignored.

- VisIt 2.6
- IPython 0.13
- Mac OSX 10.8.3

---

## Edit:

```
import sys
print sys.path
```

**ipython**

```
['',
 '/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin',
 '/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.2.1-py2.7.egg',
 '/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MeshPy-2013.1-py2.7-macosx-10.8-x86_64.egg',
 '/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pytest-2.3.4-py2.7.egg',
 '/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pytools-2012.1-py2.7.egg',
 '/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/py-1.4.13-py2.7.egg',
 '/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/decorator-3.4.0-py2.7.egg',
 '/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/astropy-0.3.dev3763-py2.7-macosx-10.8-x86_64.egg',
 '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-1.2.1-py2.7.egg',
 '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/matplotlib-1.2.0-py2.7-macosx-10.8-intel.egg',
 '/Users/lzkelley/Applications/visit/VisIt.app/Contents/Resources/2.6.1/darwin-x86_64/lib/site-packages',
 '/Users/lzkelley',
 '/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python27.zip',
 '/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7',
 '/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin',
 '/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac',
 '/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages',
 '/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/readline',
 '/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/Users/lzkelley/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages',
 '/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
 '/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PIL',
 '/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PyObjC',
 '/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg-info',
 '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages',
 '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/PIL',
 '/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/extensions']
```

**python**

```
['',
 '/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.2.1-py2.7.egg',
 '/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MeshPy-2013.1-py2.7-macosx-10.8-x86_64.egg',
 '/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pytest-2.3.4-py2.7.egg',
 '/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pytools-2012.1-py2.7.egg',
 '/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/py-1.4.13-py2.7.egg',
 '/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/decorator-3.4.0-py2.7.egg',
 '/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/astropy-0.3.dev3763-py2.7-macosx-10.8-x86_64.egg',
 '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-1.2.1-py2.7.egg',
 '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/matplotlib-1.2.0-py2.7-macosx-10.8-intel.egg',
 '/Users/lzkelley/Applications/visit/VisIt.app/Contents/Resources/2.6.1/darwin-x86_64/lib/site-packages',
 '/Users/lzkelley',
 '/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python27.zip',
 '/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7',
 '/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin',
 '/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac',
 '/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages',
 '/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/readline',
 '/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/Users/lzkelley/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages',
 '/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
 '/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PIL',
 '/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PyObjC',
 '/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg-info',
 '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages',
 '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/PIL']
```

**visit -cli**

```
['',
 '/Users/lzkelley/Applications/visit/VisIt.app/Contents/Resources/2.6.1/darwin-x86_64/bin',
 '/Users/lzkelley/Applications/visit/VisIt.app/Contents/Resources/2.6.1/darwin-x86_64/lib/site-packages',
 '/Users/lzkelley',
 '/Users/lzkelley/Applications/visit/VisIt.app/Contents/Resources/2.6.1/darwin-x86_64/lib/python/lib/python26.zip',
 '/Users/lzkelley/Applications/visit/VisIt.app/Contents/Resources/2.6.1/darwin-x86_64/lib/python/lib/python2.6',
 '/Users/lzkelley/Applications/visit/VisIt.app/Contents/Resources/2.6.1/darwin-x86_64/lib/python/lib/python2.6/plat-darwin',
 '/Users/lzkelley/Applications/visit/VisIt.app/Contents/Resources/2.6.1/darwin-x86_64/lib/python/lib/python2.6/plat-mac',
 '/Users/lzkelley/Applications/visit/VisIt.app/Contents/Resources/2.6.1/darwin-x86_64/lib/python/lib/python2.6/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages',
 '/Users/lzkelley/Applications/visit/VisIt.app/Contents/Resources/2.6.1/darwin-x86_64/lib/python/lib/python2.6/lib-tk',
 '/Users/lzkelley/Applications/visit/VisIt.app/Contents/Resources/2.6.1/darwin-x86_64/lib/python/lib/python2.6/lib-old',
 '/Users/lzkelley/Applications/visit/VisIt.app/Contents/Resources/2.6.1/darwin-x86_64/lib/python/lib/python2.6/lib-dynload',
 '/Users/lzkelley/Applications/visit/VisIt.app/Contents/Resources/2.6.1/darwin-x86_64/lib/python/lib/python2.6/site-packages',
 '/Users/lzkelley/Applications/visit/VisIt.app/Contents/Resources/2.6.1/darwin-x86_64/lib/python/lib/python2.6/site-packages/PIL',
 '/Users/lzkelley/Applications/visit/VisIt.app/Contents/Resources/2.6.1/darwin-x86_64/lib/site-packages']
```

Comment: Do you have multiple python versions installed?

Comment: @ThomasFenzl yes, I have numerous versions of python installed via macports, but (I think) only one version of ipython (`py27-ipython @0.13.2`).  In general I use python 2.7.3 (selected with `python_select`)

Comment: can you check if ipython uses the same python in the background as your shell? You can e.g. `import sys; print sys.path` and check in both

Comment: @ThomasFenzl printing sys.path yielded very long, very similar results from python and ipython (but not identical) - not sure what to look for.  `which python` yields `/opt/local/bin/python`, `which ipython` gives `/opt/local/bin/ipython` which itself contains: `#!/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python`

Comment: @ThomasFenzl when I start python from those two locations (`/opt/local/bin/python`, and `/opt/local/Library/Frameworks...`) they both say `Python 2.7.3 (default, Nov  6 2012, 01:23:28)`

Comment: and both can import visit?

Comment: what does `import sys; print sys.path` give you?

Comment: @ThomasFenzl, first thanks for working through this with me!  I've added the output to the question above

Comment: Looks reasonable... What is visit-cli, is it a python file? Then you could check what startup things they do.

Comment: @ThomasFenzl visit -cli means run visit using the command line interface, which uses the python interpreter.  How do I check startup operations?

Comment: So visit is the command and -cli an option? Sorry, didn't see that. You can use `file $(which visit)` to check what type it is.

Comment: @ThomasFenzl Yeah, cli is an option - and I just saw that the python version is 2.6.4, I just added the sys.path to the question above

Comment: Doing that command yeilds: /Users/lzkelley/Applications/visit/VisIt.app/Contents/Resources/bin/visit: POSIX shell script text executable

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29870/discussion-between-thomas-fenzl-and-zhermes)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you guys figured this out, but I'm not sure it is possible unless you build visit from scratch.  If you download their binary, it installs its own python, and resets your PYTHONPATH, and adds certain libraries.  Looking at their launch script (bin/visit) it SHOULD be possible to build VisIt to use a system python, at which point you could likely encourage it to use a system ipython instead.  But this would be done at VisIt configure time, not at runtime.

That said, if you did figure out a way to hack things out, please post an answer because I want to know too!

Answer (score 0):

Getting this running on OSX is harder because of hardcoded python paths you have to manually fix with your own python, like anaconda 2.

VisIt is built with Python 2, therefore the imports will not work with python 3.

Here is an OSX script:

[OSX import configuration](http://visitusers.org/forum/YaBB.pl?num=1367888266)

Otherwise in windows according to the VisitManual you can simply append your visit install path and import visit and launch it with a script like:

```
import sys
import os

sys.path.append("C:/Program Files/LLNL/VisIt 2.12.2/lib/site-packages")

winSavePath = os.getenv('USERPROFILE')

import visit
visit.Launch()

import visit_utils as vu
```

All subsequent calls are `visit.OpenDatabase()` as an example

There is a Linux version of Visit, perhaps that could be modified for OSX.